# Resonance vs Undamped response

Tags: resonance

[image]

Why does this book say that resonance only occurs in an RLC circuit?
If I have a two pole complex conjugagte system where the damping factor is low, there will be a resonant peak in the frequency response of that system, it is not necessary that there is a cap AND an inductor present, right?

Comment: You made me curious: can you show an example of an RL or RC circuit that has a very high Q (or even >0.5)?

Comment: Where does it say 'only'?

Comment: @Chu 'Resonance occurs in any circuit that has at least one inductor and one capacitor' 'Resonance is a condition in an RLC circuit..'

Comment: So my question really is - When I see a resonant peak in the frequency response of a system, it is 100% confirmed that the system must have at least one inductor and one capacitor? I.e there is no way to have a system with a complex conjugate pair of poles that shows a resonant peak without having an inductor and cap?

Comment: ... yes, but that doesn't excluded resonance from occurring in any other type of system.

Comment: ... e.g. systems containing piezoelectric devices; also any system with a feedback loop is a potential candidate.

Comment: @Chu Ok, so if I have a closed-loop circuit with unknown components. If it displays a resonant peak in the closed loop frequency response, can I deduce that the circuit has at least 1 capacitor and 1 inductor or is that not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a 2 pole conjugate mechanical system with springs and weights: it doesn't have an inductor or a capacitor.

And resonance is also a characteristic of an RC circuit with inductance and capacitance.

It's even possible to create mixed systems with a transducer and capacitance or inductance.

But it's not possible to create a resonant system unless you have out-of-phase energy storage. In particular, it's not possible to create a 2 pole conjugate resonate system unless you have some form of out-of-phase energy storage.

The phase response may be due to a physical inductor or capacitor, or it may be due to any kind of storage with electronic phase control. You may build an 'inductor' out of op-amps and capacitors: this was standard for electronic filters before they were replaced with digital filters.

Comment: Ok. Let's say we limit ourselves to circuits. If someone gives me a black box circuit and I put it in a closed loop feedback config and measure the closed loop freq response. If I see a resonant peak, I can then say with 100% certainty that the black box contains at least 1 inductor and at least 1 capacitor.

Comment: @alayoiskgfbfqhxjiw Thank you. I have extend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A resonance is observed when there is some cancellation of positive and negative reactive components. A (passive) circuit without inductors can't have positive reactance elements, so no cancellation can occur.

Therefore *some* inductive element is required.